# Microsoft edge not syncing in linux

Tags: linux, debian, sync, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-app

My edge doesnt sync passwords on linux. I keyed in Edge://sync-internals and got an error for passwords only, the rest are green.

[image]

This is on debian linux

this is the error:

`Error: DataTypeManagerImpl@components/sync/driver/data_type_manager_impl.cc:180, datatype error was encountered: Preexisting controller error on Sync startup`

Comment: Have you updated Edge to the latest version? First releases of a product are often bug ridden.

Comment: Yes @DrMoishePippik I updated to the latest version

Comment: oh i worked after i manually deleted the data folder in ~/.config/microsoft-edge/ thanks

Comment: @EliHeists, if you found/figured the answer to your question, add it below as answer and accept it (so that the solution that helped you is clear for future visitors with this issue.)